# How to get result from Firebase Authentication login

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The issue is that I split the code into different files.
The problem is that, I have four files, Activity, Presenter and DbHelper (handling all database calls).

That is how I call Register function:

```
// Listens for register button click
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        // Get string values from fields
        email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
        password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
        confirmPassword = confirmPasswordEditText.getText().toString();

        // If all fields are filled out and passwords match, register the user
        if (checkFields(emailEditText, passwordEditText, confirmPasswordEditText)) {
            mPresenter.onRegisterClick(email, password);
        }
    });
}
```

And inside the presenter it calls function from DbHelper:

```
public void onRegisterClick(String email, String password){
    getDataManager().registerUser(email, password);
}
```

That's how DbHelper looks:

```
@Override
    public void registerUser(String email, String password){
        FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    // Attempts to register the user with Firebase
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        // Occurs if a user can be registered
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {

                // Instantiate a new user object
                User user = new User();

               insertUser(user, mAuth.getUid());
            }
        })
        // Occurs if a user can't be registered
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // to add on failure
            }
        });
}
```

The problem is that Firebase Authentication has it's own listeners OnSuccess and OnFailure. So for example I would like to change the UI on success and I would need to call a function from the Presenter class (or at least Activity class). The problem is, that I cannot do that from DbHelper as it does not have the access to context. I could pass the context from Activity to DbHelper through arguments but it does not seem right.
Is there any way to change the UI correctly on the result?
FirebaseAuth already has it's own listener 'AuthStateListener', however, I would not be able to track the result of registration, I could only track if user registered I could put him to main page.

So the question is, how do I change UI on success, if this piece of code (with registering and successes) is in separate file.

Comment: "I could pass the context from Activity to DbHelper through arguments but it does not seem right." Why not? If you want the auth handler to change the UI, that seems to be the only way to do so. If you want the UI to be changed in the `registerUser` method, consider returning the `Task` from `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to the caller and add your `addOnSuccessListener` there.

Comment: I think this article, [How to create a clean Firebase authentication using MVVM?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336), might help you achieve a clean Firebase Authentication with Java. If you understand Kotlin, then this article [How to handle Firebase Authentication in clean architecture using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8), might also help.